# Does Java ArrayList<Object> maintain its sequence if its converted to JSON(Serialized) & then read back?

Tags: java, arraylist, serialization

I have a case of posting a Workflow comprising of sequential steps through a kafka topic. There is a sequence of about 15 steps, and I first generate the sequence, post it to kafka topic where it gets read, execute one sequence, and then post it back to kafka.

For this to happen, the important aspect is to maintain the sequence correctly. I thought of using a Graph like data-structure, but I was curious if I used a simple Java Arraylist , would that work?

Answer (score 0):

JSON supports arrays / lists, they have an order. The other data structure are maps / dictionaries / key-value pairs, they do not have an order.

An ArrayList is properly serializable to the first data type and therefore retain its order.